# PULSE on github (link provided) RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory.... preventing the program "run.py" from executing

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, dlib

(As a student I am kind of new to this but did quite a bit of research and I got pretty far, I'm super into learning something new through this!)

This issue is for the project pulse -> https://github.com/adamian98/pulse

the readme if you scroll down a bit on the page, gives a much better explanation than I could. It will also give a direct "correct" path to judge my actions against and make solving the problem a lot easier.

Objective: run program using the run.py file

Issue: I got a "RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory" despite having a compatible gpu and enough vram

Knowledge: when it comes to coding i just started a few days ago and have a dozen hours with anaconda now, comfterable creating environments.

What I did was... (the list below is a summary and the specific details are after it)

1. install anaconda
2. use this .yml file -> https://github.com/leihuayi/pulse/blob/feature/docker/pulse.yml (it changes dependencies to work for windows which is why I needed to grab a different one than the one supplied on the master github page) to create a new environment and install the required packages. It worked fantastically! I only got an error trying to install dlib, it didn't seem compatible with A LOT of the packages and my python version.
3. I installed the cuda toolkit 10.2 , cmake 3.17.2, and tried to install dlib into the environment directly. the errors spat out in a blaze of glory. The dlib package seems to be only needed for a different .py file and not run.py though so I think it may be unrelated to this error

logs are below and I explain my process in more detail

START DETAILS AND LOGS: from here until the "DETAILS 2" section should be enough information to solve, the rest past there is in case

error log for runing out of memory--> (after executing the "run.py" file)

```
Loading Synthesis Network
Loading Mapping Network
Running Mapping Network
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\micha\anaconda3\envs\Pulse1\pulse-master\run.py", line 58, in
model = PULSE(cache_dir=kwargs["cache_dir"])
File "C:\Users\micha\anaconda3\envs\Pulse1\pulse-master\PULSE.py", line 44, in init
latent_out = torch.nn.LeakyReLU(5)(mapping(latent))
File "C:\Users\micha\anaconda3\envs\pulse3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 550, in call
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\micha\anaconda3\envs\Pulse1\pulse-master\stylegan.py", line 233, in forward
x = super().forward(x)
File "C:\Users\micha\anaconda3\envs\pulse3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 100, in forward
input = module(input)
File "C:\Users\micha\anaconda3\envs\pulse3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 550, in call
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\micha\anaconda3\envs\Pulse1\pulse-master\stylegan.py", line 38, in forward
return F.linear(x, self.weight * self.w_mul, bias)
File "C:\Users\micha\anaconda3\envs\pulse3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1610, in linear
ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.91 GiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 3.92 GiB already allocated; 744.91 MiB free; 3.93 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

End of error log.

NVIDIA-SMI LOG WHILE RUNNING (checking free memory)

```
C:\Users\micha>nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv --loop=1
memory.free [MiB]
```

> 5991 MiB
> 5991 MiB
> 5991 MiB
> 5991 MiB
> 5897 MiB
> 5781 MiB
> 5685 MiB
> 1643 MiB
> 5991 MiB
> 5991 MiB

the program stopped at the 1643MiB

DETAILS PART 1:

I have an nvidia gpu with 6gb of memory which, (according to other logs posted by the creator of the project-> should have enough memory for this to work "We ran our tests with 8GB of memory but I believe that you should be able to run the code with 4GB as well" -adamian98 ). I'm trying to fix that error and get the run.py to work as intended.

Here is the system info using the `numba -s` command in anaconda (includes hardware info: gpu, my windows version, memory, python version etc.)

START CUDA INFO

> ```
> Hardware Information
> Machine : AMD64
> CPU Name : znver1
> CPU Count : 16
> Number of accessible CPUs : 16
> List of accessible CPUs cores : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
> CFS Restrictions (CPUs worth of runtime) : None
>
> CPU Features : 64bit adx aes avx avx2 bmi bmi2
> clflushopt clwb clzero cmov cx16
> cx8 f16c fma fsgsbase fxsr lzcnt
> mmx movbe mwaitx pclmul popcnt
> prfchw rdpid rdrnd rdseed sahf sha
> sse sse2 sse3 sse4.1 sse4.2 sse4a
> ssse3 wbnoinvd xsave xsavec
> xsaveopt xsaves
>
> Memory Total (MB) : 15789
> Memory Available (MB) : 8421
>
> OS Information
> Platform Name : Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
> Platform Release : 10
> OS Name : Windows
> OS Version : 10.0.18362
> OS Specific Version : 10 10.0.18362 SP0 Multiprocessor Free
> Libc Version : ?
>
> Python Information
> Python Compiler : MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)
> Python Implementation : CPython
> Python Version : 3.8.5
> Python Locale : en_CA.cp1252
>
> LLVM Information
> LLVM Version : 10.0.1
>
> CUDA Information
> CUDA Device Initialized : True
> CUDA Driver Version : 10020
> CUDA Detect Output:
> Found 1 CUDA devices
> id 0 b'GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with Max-Q Design' [SUPPORTED]
> compute capability: 7.5
> pci device id: 0
> pci bus id: 1
> Summary:
> 1/1 devices are supported
>
> CUDA Librairies Test Output:
> Finding cublas from
> named cublas.dll
> trying to open library... ERROR: failed to open cublas:
> Could not find module 'cublas.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
> Finding cusparse from
> named cusparse.dll
> trying to open library... ERROR: failed to open cusparse:
> Could not find module 'cusparse.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
> Finding cufft from
> named cufft.dll
> trying to open library... ERROR: failed to open cufft:
> Could not find module 'cufft.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
> Finding curand from
> named curand.dll
> trying to open library... ERROR: failed to open curand:
> Could not find module 'curand.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
> Finding nvvm from
> named nvvm.dll
> trying to open library... ERROR: failed to open nvvm:
> Could not find module 'nvvm.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
> Finding cudart from
> named cudart.dll
> trying to open library... ERROR: failed to open cudart:
> Could not find module 'cudart.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
> Finding libdevice from
> searching for compute_20... ERROR: can't open libdevice for compute_20
> searching for compute_30... ERROR: can't open libdevice for compute_30
> searching for compute_35... ERROR: can't open libdevice for compute_35
> searching for compute_50... ERROR: can't open libdevice for compute_50
>
> ROC information
> ROC Available : False
> ROC Toolchains : None
> HSA Agents Count : 0
> HSA Agents:
> None
> HSA Discrete GPUs Count : 0
> HSA Discrete GPUs : None
>
> SVML Information
> SVML State, config.USING_SVML : True
> SVML Library Loaded : True
> llvmlite Using SVML Patched LLVM : True
> SVML Operational : True
>
> Threading Layer Information
> TBB Threading Layer Available : False
> +--> Disabled due to Unknown import problem.
> OpenMP Threading Layer Available : True
> +-->Vendor: MS
> Workqueue Threading Layer Available : True
> +-->Workqueue imported successfully.
>
> Numba Environment Variable Information
> None found.
>
> Conda Information
> Conda Build : 3.20.5
> Conda Env : 4.9.2
> Conda Platform : win-64
> Conda Python Version : 3.8.5.final.0
> Conda Root Writable : True
>
> Installed Packages
> blas 1.0 mkl
> ca-certificates 2020.12.8 haa95532_0
> certifi 2020.12.5 py38haa95532_0
> cffi 1.14.0 py38h7a1dbc1_0
> chardet 3.0.4 py38haa95532_1003
> cryptography 2.9.2 py38h7a1dbc1_0
> cudatoolkit 10.2.89 h74a9793_1 anaconda
> cycler 0.10.0 py38_0
> freetype 2.9.1 ha9979f8_1
> icc_rt 2019.0.0 h0cc432a_1
> icu 58.2 ha925a31_3
> idna 2.9 py_1
> intel-openmp 2019.4 245
> jpeg 9b hb83a4c4_2
> kiwisolver 1.2.0 py38h74a9793_0
> libcxx 7.0.0 h1ad3211_1002 conda-forge
> libpng 1.6.37 h2a8f88b_0
> libtiff 4.1.0 h56a325e_0
> llvm-meta 7.0.0 0 conda-forge
> m2-bash 4.3.042 5
> m2-gcc-libs 5.3.0 4
> m2-libedit 3.1 20150326
> m2-libffi 3.2.1 2
> m2-libreadline 6.3.008 8
> m2-msys2-runtime 2.5.0.17080.65c939c 3
> m2-ncurses 6.0.20160220 2
> m2w64-gcc-libgfortran 5.3.0 6
> m2w64-gcc-libs-core 5.3.0 7
> m2w64-gmp 6.1.0 2
> m2w64-libwinpthread-git 5.0.0.4634.697f757 2
> matplotlib 3.1.3 py38_0
> matplotlib-base 3.1.3 py38h64f37c6_0
> mkl 2019.4 245
> mkl-service 2.3.0 py38h196d8e1_0
> mkl_fft 1.0.15 py38h14836fe_0
> mkl_random 1.1.0 py38hf9181ef_0
> msys2-conda-epoch 20160418 1
> ninja 1.9.0 py38h74a9793_0
> numpy 1.18.1 py38h93ca92e_0
> numpy-base 1.18.1 py38hc3f5095_1
> olefile 0.46 py_0
> openssl 1.1.1i h2bbff1b_0
> pandas 1.0.3 py38h47e9c7a_0
> pillow 7.1.2 py38hcc1f983_0
> pip 20.0.2 py38_3
> powershell_shortcut 0.0.1 3
> pycparser 2.20 py_2
> pyopenssl 19.1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
> pyparsing 2.4.7 py_0
> pyqt 5.9.2 py38ha925a31_4
> pysocks 1.7.1 py38haa95532_0
> python 3.8.2 he1778fa_13
> python-dateutil 2.8.1 py_0
> pytorch 1.5.0 py3.8_cuda102_cudnn7_0 pytorch
> pytz 2020.1 py_0
> qt 5.9.7 vc14h73c81de_0
> requests 2.23.0 py38_0
> scipy 1.4.1 py38h9439919_0
> setuptools 46.2.0 py38_0
> sip 4.19.13 py38ha925a31_0
> six 1.14.0 py38haa95532_0
> sqlite 3.31.1 h2a8f88b_1
> tk 8.6.8 hfa6e2cd_0
> torchvision 0.6.0 py38_cu102 pytorch
> tornado 6.0.4 py38he774522_1
> urllib3 1.25.8 py38_0
> vc 14.2 h21ff451_1
> vs2015_runtime 14.27.29016 h5e58377_2
> wheel 0.34.2 py38_0
> win_inet_pton 1.1.0 py38haa95532_0
> wincertstore 0.2 py38_0
> xz 5.2.5 h62dcd97_0
> zlib 1.2.11 h62dcd97_4
> zstd 1.3.7 h508b16e_0
>
> No errors reported.
>
> Warning log
> Warning (roc): Error initialising ROC: No ROC toolchains found.
> Warning (roc): No HSA Agents found, encountered exception when searching: Error at driver init:
>
> HSA is not currently supported on this platform (win32).`
> ```

END CUDA INFO

The section below is most likely not needed for this question, here in case:

DETAILS PART 2 (It sounded like dlib (and cmake) were only required to align the faces before therefore theoretically it isn't needed in run.py, but I'm not 100 percent sure. I omitted the section including the dlib specific errors):

I got the .yml installed successfully into the anaconda environment I named "pulse3" with no errors as well as the CUDA toolkit 10.2 and cmake 3.17.2. Dlib is the only thing that gave me some trouble spiting out a bunch of incompatibility errors with the other packages on windows with my python version 3.8.2.

Comment: I cannot see there a report on free memory on the NVidia card. If your Windows graphics is also running on the card, then there might not be enough space left.

Comment: Here is the specific line detailing free memory.                                                          >       GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 3.92 GiB already allocated; 744.91 MiB free; 3.93 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)                                                                        I have integrated graphics that runs windows graphics and should be doing so. The dedicated graphics are at 0 percent usage in task manager so im unsure why only 745 MiB is free.

Comment: task manager might not be the best tool. try something like gpuz to check more in detail. From the error, there are 3.92 GiB already taken and 1.91 requested. That is a very tight fit if there is anything other running or the output it is giving you is not correct. Are you sure that the line you quote from the devs is about GPU memory and not about RAM? Because from your error message, it would never fit into 4GB GPU memory

Comment: Double checked about vram VS ram. Replying to someone using a gtx 750ti they said-> "Unfortunately 2GB is not enough memory to store all of the gradients necessary during optimization. We ran our tests with 8GB of memory but I believe that you should be able to run the code with 4GB as well." This means that it is possible that their speculation was incorrect since they never tested it. My gpu has 6144MB total memory and trying 10 tests running the program with gpuz open I found 4300MB peak. I had a very steady 153MB base memory usage with nothing other than gpuz open.

Comment: Do you think it may be possible to allocate more vram to the program in this situation? I feel like there is headroom. But, i'm unsure what might be taking up the memory with nothing else running on the card.

Comment: New insight! The nvidia-smi log while the program was running was added. Importantly  it shows the free memory when the error was thrown >    5897 MiB
>    5781 MiB
>    5685 MiB
>    1643 MiB
>    5991 MiB
>    5991 MiB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on new log evidence using this script simultaneously alongside the run.py file

> ```
>  "C:\Users\micha>nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv --loop=1"
> ```

alongside using gpuz to monitor,

as well as the error produced from executing run.py in an anaconda environment with all required packages except dlib installed correctly:

> ```
> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.91 GiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 3.92 GiB already allocated; 744.91 MiB free; 3.93 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
> ```

resulted in a **logged usage of up to but not exceeding 4.502GB of VRAM on a gtx 1660ti**

**Therefore, I can  strongly infer that the project PULSE: Self-Supervised Photo Upsampling via Latent Space Exploration of Generative Models (https://github.com/adamian98/pulse) does need somewhere between 6.01GB and 8.00GB of VRAM to execute the "run.py" file, therefore a gpu with 6gb is insufficient**

so the error:

> ```
> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.91 GiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 3.92 GiB already allocated; 744.91 MiB free; 3.93 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
> ```

**is most likely due to hardware limitations.**

**Notes To Help Improve the Pulse Project:**

This result, though inconclusive, contradicts this theory from the creator of the project:

"Unfortunately 2GB is not enough memory to store all of the gradients necessary during optimization. **We ran our tests with 8GB of memory** but I believe that you should be able to run the code with 4GB as well." -adamian98

**Possible factors of error** (see logs in question for more info if needed):

1.needing to execute the .py file from outside the anaconda environment (despite having the file inside the environment as well)

2.lack of successful dlib package installation

3.the input image not being the correct size (it was 75x77 pixels, and was yoinked from the project samples)

4.the input image not being the correct format (it was.png)

5. the image not being in the correct place \anaconda3\envs\pulse3\Library\qml\Qt3D
   (the anaconda environment was named pulse3 that is why the path uses pulse3)